# Bought some backlink but how to use it?

Tags: seo

I have bought a lot of backlink but not sure how to get started with it.
like any software to backlink the website or any guide to buld the backlinker.

actually i got no idea on how backlinker in the market works,
what the algorithm behind actually ? Is there any open sources or tutorial to get started with ?

Comment: Google is employing more and more filtering against obvious SEO attempts, so you might be worse off in the end. If I were you I'd put my efforts in making the content / service better.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. If you bought backlinks I guess some pages will now link to your website. And then you hope google is stupid enough to think they are real links raising your page rank.

Comment: Using content copied from other websites doesn't help your pagerank either. And it's a copyright violation too. Especially if you remove the author information.

Comment: It looks to me like most of you blog content is stolen without crediting the original author.

Comment: the backlink is bought and USD 5 only and no services...i gonna build a new website is not copying other content but hope someway to increase my PR =D

Comment: wondering any way to backlink...

Comment: 1. You're worried about PageRank - why?
2. You're buying backlinks when it's clearly against most search engines TOC - why?
How about creating something uniquely interesting that is of value (to someone). If it's good enough, people will link to it. If it's not - then you're wasting your time and polluting the internet.

Comment: just trying to opening a way for my website while now many company pay few thousand or million to boost their page rank...if i do nothing for SEO, even power content also will not find by user while my content is too common and push down by other paid companion XD

Comment: "Content is King". Write good, interesting, useful content and the visitors/backlinks will come. I have a blog that ranks very highly for its chosen keywords and it has never been promoted and I have never tried to get backlinks, even though it has thousands. What it does offer is technical manual downloads and the users flock from across the globe. If people have a reason to come to your site they will.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to backlinks, I hope you are talking about backlinks that are relevant to your web site, meaning if your web site covers Titanic, the movie of James Cameron, it is arguably helpful to your SEO if you get a link from movie related web site, or a web site/page focus on James Cameron. Depending on the intelligence of Google, which BTW we do not know, if you get a link from Cameron' own blog if he has your SEO may also benefit.

Anyway, my point is you need to make sure all of the sites / pages  from which you purchased links are focused on the same genre as your site does. Otherwise you are wastering your money and time. Even if you may get some juicy from links that have nothing to do with your site, sooner or latter, Google and other search engines will find out. The reason is simple, people which click your link from those sites find your web site has nothing to do with the web site they are browsing. It is annoying to users and Google (As Google claimed they are helping people finding information)

Now, if you brought good links, the best option is to put your home page link on them. however, depending on your landing page, and the relevance between your site and other sites you got links, you may consider put it on other pages as well.

I hope I made myself clear

Comment: understand =D means when we link other site from our site, conclusion is the site link from my site will get benefit if i got huge volume of visitor. at the same way, content of site link by me, should exact information as what i have...i mean at least related, else google will track and record this then no help with the visit... am i right ?